# HTML Form Submit Action

Tags: html, forms

I've set up a contact form in html but whenever the user submits a message, the page reloads. I've seen some examples where this can be corrected using ajax, but I'm not sure how to go about it. This is my form, together with the php code behind it:

```
<form id="email-form" action="index.html" method="post" role="form" target="_blank">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-input" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-input" name="email" id="email"  value="" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea rows="6" id="message" name="message" class="form-input" placeholder="Talk to us about maths!"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="main-button" type="submit" id="submit">Send Message</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'Maths website'; 
$to = 'my@email.com'; 
$subject = 'Maths Message';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {

  if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
      echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
      echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }
  } else {
    echo '<p>You need to fill in all the fields!</p>';
  }

}
```

Also - note that the the form tag has `action="index.html"`. Will this still work? I've added the line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` to my .htaccess file, but I'm not sure if this will work for the action keword.

Comment: There is nothing to do with action attribute. You have to use javascript to call ajax.

Comment: @instead Can you give me an example to get me started?

Comment: @Dhruvi Mistry already gave You simple example. Should work after few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

use below code with your required modification :

```
 <form action="index.php" method="post"id="formid" > 
 <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required><br><br>
 <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required><br>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function() {
                var name= $("#name").val();
                var password= $("#password").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: "name=" + name+ "&password=" + password,
                    success: function(data) {
                       alert("sucess");
                    }
                });


            });
    });
</script>



<?php //insert.php 
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "ajax";


  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

 // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $pass=$_POST['password'];
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO insert_tbl(name,pass)     VALUES('".$name."','".$pass."')")    

  ?>
```

Comment: You should add e.preventDefault() to submit function.

Comment: Simply copy -paste this code in your local files and have a look. It does not need e.preventDefault() here.. you can use that also but with bit different changes..

Comment: Your code send ajax and immediately send form which reload page. It is just wrong. It should send form by AJAX and don't reload page.